# iframe of a shinyapp in rmarkdown

Tags: r, iframe, r-markdown, shiny

I am trying to embed a shinyapp in an rmarkdown file, if possible in full screen. Checking other answers, I tried this that works for this youtube:

```
---
title: "Derek Corcoran"
---

Some text

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Some more text
```

but when I try with my shiny app it does not work:

```
---
title: "Derek Corcoran"
---

Some text

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://derek-corcoran.shinyapps.io/WhereShouldYouLive/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Some more text
```

### Some other options I tried:

```
---
title: "Derek Corcoran"
---

Some text

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://derek-corcoran.shinyapps.io/WhereShouldYouLive/"></iframe>

Some more text
```

I just get an empty square

```
---
title: "Derek Corcoran"
---

Some text

<iframe src="https://derek-corcoran.shinyapps.io/WhereShouldYouLive/"></iframe>

Some more text
```

Smaller empty square.

Any ideas

Comment: I'm not sure here - my first suspicion would be CSP headers in either parent or child - maybe opening the network inspector while loading could bring some clarity...

Answer (score 4):

Fixed it with

````
```{r}
knitr::include_app("https://derek-corcoran.shinyapps.io/WhereShouldYouLive/")
```
````